# Comparing means of different training programs in R

Tags: r, regression, anova, t-test

I have a data set with performance and training data that looks something like (this is not the exact data, but gives a general idea):

```
>dat
Performance Training
1           1
0           1
1           2
0           2
1           3
1           3
```

I want to find if there is are any significant differences between performance means for the respective levels of performance in R.  I have tried linear regression and anova, such as: `summary(lm(performance~training))` or `summary(aov(performance~training))` both of which yield non-significant results.  However, when I do a T-test to compare some of the means manually it is telling be significant differences exist.  Any thoughts on how to code what I am looking for or what might be going on here?

Comment: What do you mean by 'between performance means for the respective levels of performance'?

Comment: I mean comparing means at each level of training.  For example in the sample data I provided the mean performance score for the first training (training 1) was .5, same for training 2, and a mean of 1 for training 3.

Comment: What kind of variables are these? Is `Performance` binary (eg, pass / fail)? Does `Training` refer to different types of training or units of the same training (eg, 1-3 hours of training)?

Comment: Although this question asks about code, the underlying confusion seems to be about misunderstanding the statistical issues involved. IMO, it should be considered on topic here.